# After upgrading to Skype 8.25, ditto always crashes when Skype is launched. Why?

Tags: windows-7, crash, skype, ditto

After upgrading to Skype 8.25, ditto always crashes when Skype is launched. Why?

I use Skype 8.25 with Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate. I didn't have such issues before upgrading from Skype 7 to Skype 8.25.

[image]

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: Ditto.exe
  Application Version:  3.18.46.0
  Application Timestamp:    509c7562
  Fault Module Name:    gaming_spy.dll
  Fault Module Version: 18.2.3827.0
  Fault Module Timestamp:   5a954918
  Exception Code:   c0000005
  Exception Offset: 0000000000004382
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 54ba
  Additional Information 2: 54ba3c96664ce317733e6fed30788a44
  Additional Information 3: f965
  Additional Information 4: f96538f69a1af249eb3b23d8223f09b4

Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
  C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt
```

---

I have also noted that a few other programs are much more likely to crash after Skype 8 is opened, such as Dragon NaturallySpeaking 12.5  Professional, Point-N-Click 2.10.0.1, Display Fusion 5.0.1.0, and Windows Explorer, but unlike Ditto they don't crash systematically.

[image]

```
Description:
  A problem caused this program to stop interacting with Windows.

Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   AppHangXProcB1
  Application Name: DisplayFusion.exe
  Application Version:  5.0.1.0
  Application Timestamp:    517a895f
  Hang Signature:   56fe
  Hang Type:    272
  Waiting on Application Name:  Point-N-Click.exe
  Waiting on Application Version:   2.10.0.1
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Hang Signature 1:  56fe7ab4a5a696d7b4e34219b39853a6
  Additional Hang Signature 2:  bf96
  Additional Hang Signature 3:  bf96af6014170717d1349d565c79bc35
  Additional Hang Signature 4:  56fe
  Additional Hang Signature 5:  56fe7ab4a5a696d7b4e34219b39853a6
  Additional Hang Signature 6:  bf96
  Additional Hang Signature 7:  bf96af6014170717d1349d565c79bc35

Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409
```

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
  C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt

Comment: Try to deactivate your AVAST antivirus